# Why are my member function's not working?

Tags: c++, function, error-handling

I am writing my a computer program for my computer program class, but for some reason I can't run my program due to an error's that involve my member functions. I keep getting the error message

"Error error C3490: 'den' cannot be modified because it is being accessed through a const object"

What have I done wrong to get this message and how can I correct it?

This is my code:

```
 // implement all class member functions here, gcd function is given

 int Fraction::gcd()
 {
if(num == 0) return 1;

        int a = max(abs(num), abs(den));
        int b = min(abs(num), abs(den));

while(b != 0)
{
    int result = a%b;
    a = b;
    b = result;
}

return a;
}
 void Fraction::input(istream& in)
{
char op;
in >> num;
in >> op;
in >> den;
if(den == 0)
{
    cout << "Wrong input. Exit the program" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
 if(den < 0)
{
 num *= -1;
 den *= -1;}
}
 void Fraction::output(ostream& out)
 {
  if(den == 0)
 out << "0";
  else
 out << num << " / " << den;
}

 Fraction::Fraction(int numerator, int denominator)
 {
   assert(denominator !=0);
   num = numerator;
   den = denominator;
if(den < 0)
{
   num *=-1;
   den *= -1;
}
}
 bool Fraction::less(const Fraction& other) const
 {
Fraction temp(other.num , other.den);
int num_1(num);
if(den != temp.den)
{
    num_1 *= temp.den;
    temp.num *= num;
}
if(num_1 < temp.num)
  {return true;}
else
  {return false;}
 }
  Fraction Fraction::reciprocal() const
 {
  Fraction tempa(num, den);
  int temp(tempa.num);
  tempa.num = tempa.den;
  tempa.den = temp;
  num = den;
if(den < 0)
{
  num *= -1;
  den *= -1;
} 
return tempa;
  }
 Fraction Fraction::neg() const
  {
  num*=-1;
  return;  
  }  
  Fraction::Fraction(int numerator)
  {
   num = numerator;
   den = 1;
  }
  Fraction::Fraction()
  {
   num = 0;
   den = 1;
}
Fraction Fraction::add(const Fraction& other) const 
{
int num_1 = num *other.den;
int num_2 = den*other.den;
int denom = den*other.den;
 Fraction result((num_1+num_2), denom);
   result.reduce();
   return result;
 }
 Fraction Fraction::div(const Fraction& other) const
 {
   Fraction temp(num, den);
   other = other.reciprocal();
   Fraction result(temp.mul(other));
   return result;
}
Fraction Fraction::sub(const Fraction& other) const
{
  int num_1 = num *other.den;
  int num_2 = den*other.den;
  int denom = den*other.den;
  Fraction result((num_1-num_2), denom);
  result.reduce();
  return result;
}
Fraction Fraction::mul(const Fraction& other) const
{
  int num_0 = num*other.num;
  int denom = den*other.den;
  Fraction result(num_0, denom);
  result.reduce();
  return result;
}
 void Fraction::reduce()
 {
  int r = gcd();
  num /= r;
  den /= r;
  if(num == 0)
    den = 1;

}
bool Fraction::less_or_equal(const Fraction& other) const
{

}
bool Fraction::greater_or_equal(const Fraction& other) const
{

}
bool Fraction::equal(const Fraction& other) const
{

}
bool Fraction::not_equal(const Fraction& other) const
{

}
bool Fraction::greater(const Fraction& other)
```

Comment: Please remove any irrelevant code and format it properly

Comment: Just as the message says, you have tried to modify `den` through a `const` object. That's exactly what you have done wrong. Is there anything unclear about the above? (Example answers: I don't know what is "modify"; I don't know what is "const"; I don't know which object is const; I don't know why it's wrong).

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to modify a member named "den" inside a const method, and you can't modify nothing inside a const, just access the data. You will need to modify your function to get rid of the const or duplicate it without the const.

Your code is difficult to read but this seem to be happening into your "reciprocal()" method.

Comment: Or declare the member to `mutable`

Comment: And this is equally happening with the `num` member as well. And the solution is neither to make them non-const nor the members mutable. Look at the functions. They're supposed to be returning a value-copy of the calculated result, not mutate the existing object. At least some of them.

Comment: Of course, this applies to every variable inside the class.

Answer (score 2):

> "Error error C3490: 'den' cannot be modified because it is being accessed through a const object"

Exactly what it says: in a member function marked with const, you've attempted to change the value of a member variable.  You've done this a couple of times that I can see.  Look at the method Fraction::reciprocal(), for example:

```
Fraction Fraction::reciprocal() const // NOTE: CONST METHOD
{
   Fraction tempa(num, den);
    int temp(tempa.num);
    tempa.num = tempa.den;
    tempa.den = temp;
    num = den;
    if(den < 0)
    {
        num *= -1;
        den *= -1; // NOTE: ATTEMPT TO MODIFY den, WHICH IS CONST
    }
}
```

Your compiler should tell you the exact line number of the instance that it's complaining about.  One solution is to remove the `const` specifier from the functions in question.

if, however, `den` is not part of the "logical state" (i.e. it's a cache value or otherwise intermediate value), then it's usually acceptable to declare the variable as `mutable` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Member functions declared with const qualifier may not change underlying objects. For example your function reciprocal is declared with qualifier const

```
  Fraction Fraction::reciprocal() const
 {
Fraction tempa(num, den);
int temp(tempa.num);
tempa.num = tempa.den;
tempa.den = temp;
num = den;
if(den < 0)
{
num *= -1;
den *= -1;
} 
return tempa;
  }
```

and inside itself it tries to modify variable den

```
if(den < 0)
{
num *= -1;
den *= -1;
}
```

If you want that functions with const qualifier could change data member den you should define it as mutable. For example

```
mutable int den; // denominator of the fraction
```

Though it would be better to redesign your member functions.